# CURL JSON response won't output to a file but displays the response on cmd prompt window

Tags: json, curl

Absolute newbie here. First question ever:

I am trying to use curl to get the activity of a private web account.

When I do the "curl -u username:authtoken URL" in the command prompt, I get a JSON string in the response which is displayed on the command prompt.

I want to output the JSON string to a simple text file instead and added the " -o output.txt " to the above curl command. The problem is, nothing is getting written to the file. HELP? I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Please show the complete command line that does not work for you.  `-o` is the correct and official way to get the output written to a file.

Comment: Here's the outline of what I am using:

curl -u username:authtoken URL -o output.txt

Comment: Some weird magic just happened. I was trying to output the JSON string to an existing file and it absolutely wouldn't write into the file. I just deleted that file and ran the command so that it would create a file and it DID and I can see the JSON string as well. Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Figured that out as well.  I did not have my file path name in double quotes. I am not very smart. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

**You can direct the output of the command to a file like so:**

`curl -u username:authtoken URL > aFile.txt`

`>` injects new content everytime. Use `>>` to append to the file without overwriting it.

**Append to file:**

`curl -u username:authtoken URL >> aFile.txt`

Comment: I tried both > and >> but neither works. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Windows 8. I figured it out though. Thanks!